# Having some issues with for loops and list.append()

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

Here is some sample code that I'm running:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

x=[] 
for i in range(0,20):
    x.append(i) 
y=[] 
for i in x:
    y.append(-1*x[i])

for i in y:
    print i, y[i]
```

The expected output is:

```
0    0
1    -1
2    -2
3    -3
4    -4
5    -5
6    -6
7    -7
8    -8
9    -9
10    -10
11    -11
12    -12
13    -13
14    -14
15    -15
16    -16
17    -17
18    -18
19    -19
```

Instead I get:

```
0 0
-1 -19
-2 -18
-3 -17
-4 -16
-5 -15
-6 -14
-7 -13
-8 -12
-9 -11
-10 -10
-11 -9
-12 -8
-13 -7
-14 -6
-15 -5
-16 -4
-17 -3
-18 -2
-19 -1
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get your wanted output:

```
for i,val in enumerate(y):
    print (i, val)
```

Your problem was that `for i in y` gives you the actual elements in y. You were then using these as indices when printing y[i]. When you use a negative number as an indice it counts backwards from the end of the list (so y[-1] is the last value in the list, y[-2] is the 2nd to last, etc).

Comment: No problem :) if you feel that either mine or someone elses answer has helped you then please vote up and [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) their answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in y:
    print i, y[i]
```

Prints i (which comes from y) and y[1], which also accesses y. I think you wanted:

```
for i in x:
    print i, y[i]
```

If is interesting to note that because your original code was sending negative numbers as the index of y (i.e. y[-1]) it was getting the elements from the end and going backwards. Fun.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in y` does *not* produce indices. It produces the numbers already stored in `y`, ranging from 0 through to -19. These negative indexes then *reapplied* to `y` give you indexes counted from the end of the list.

In other words, in the first iteration, `y[0]` is `0` and prints `0, 0`. The second iteration, `y[1]` is `-1`, and `y[-1]`, the last element in `y` is `-19` because when a negative index is used the length of the list is added to the index, so `-1 -19` is printed. Etc.

The Pythonic way to print indices together with list values is to use `enumerate()`; like this:

```
for i, value in enumerate(y):
    print i, value
```

but you could also have done:

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    print i, y[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the fact that in the last loop `for i in y`, `i` is assigned each of the *values*, not indices. Thus, `i` is assigned `-1`, `-2`, ... , `-19` and so forth. And accessing a negative index `-i` of a list returns the i-th element counting from the back of the list.

I.e.

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6][-1]
6
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6][-4]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (changes are made to the last line):

```
x=[] 
for i in range(0,20):
    x.append(i) 
y=[] 
for i in x:
    y.append(-1*x[i])

for i in y:
    print x[-i], y[-i]
```

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected output is caused by the last loop.

```
for i in y:
```

i is looping over the values of y which are the values you see in the first column

since the values for i are negative in this loop you will get the index from the end first starting at -1 being equal to the last element, -2 being the second to last, etc. Of course the zero index is non-negative and indexes from the beginning of the array

to get the values for i you are expecting you could loop over the values in x[] or over the range of index values in y

```
for i in x:
    print i, y[i]
```

or

```
for i in range(0,len(y)):
    print i, y[i]
```